# Detecting identical combination of two columns within a R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, combinations

I have this following R dataframe:

```
       OffspringID1 OffspringID2 Relation Replicate
1           ID24          ID1 PO  3
2           ID29         ID31 PO  3
3           ID31         ID82 PO  3
4           ID44         ID75 PO  3
5           ID1         ID24 HS  9
6           ID1         ID51 HS  9
7           ID1         ID54 HS  9
8           ID1         ID55 HS  9
9           ID1         ID83 HS  9
```

and so on. I would like to grep the number of observations per level of the factor "Relation", for each combination of individuals (OffspringID1/OffspringID2) that are identical.

I think I could basically use a simple aggregate function, but as you may see, I could get identical but permuted pairs across rows (e.g., row 1 and row 5 display the same individuals pair but in a different order).

How could I take this into account within aggregate? And in a general way, is there a rule of thumb to detect rows resulting from columns permutations within a R dataframe?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You should first sort your Offspring ID columns so that, e.g., the lower number (or alphabetically first, perhaps) offspring is in the first column. `your_data$off1 = with(your_data, pmin(OffspringID1, OffspringID2)); your_data$off2 = with(your_data, pmax(OffspringID1, OffspringID2))`, then you can aggregate without worry using `off1` and `off2` as groupers.

Comment: Hi Gregor, thank you very much for this suggestion! I was indeed thinking of doing that if this happened to be the best solution :) which seems to be, in the end. 

Although I would be very interested in knowing how to deal with permuted columns; for instance if you have a very large dataframe with many permuted columns and you need to keep them in their original order! All the best,
Chrys

Comment: You can keep all your columns in whatever order you need, but when you aggregate you need a unique key. With 2 columns, it's easy to do min and max. With more columns the solutions I've seen are usually to sort the row values and concatenate them (or similar) to create a unique key.